# Windows API to hide desktop notifications

Tags: .net, windows, windows-10

Is there a Win API, or SHELLAPI call to ask Windows 10 to hide all notifications?  I'm looking for something similar to what you get when you manually turn on Presentation mode, where all notifications are temporarily suppressed.

Comment: Giving programs direct control over this would be problematic - too open to abuse. Instead, I think windows will suspend notifications if an application enters *full screen* mode.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bitdisaster/windows-focus-assist) library may give you an idea.